# jQuery fadeOut sets opacity to 1

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadeout

I'll keep it short, consider this line:

```
$record.fadeOut(250);
```

Where `$record` is a table row that looks like this:

```
<tr id="5194c885eb9fbf38aa000026" class="record">
   <td>Test</td>
   <td>2013/05/16 - 13:52</td>
   <td>2013/05/16 - 13:52</td>
   <td class="recordActions">
       <a title="Edit" href="/2configure/templates/devicetypes/5194c885eb9fbf38aa000026/edit" class="edit">
           <img src="/icons/document--pencil.png" alt="edit">
       </a>
       <a title="Delete" href="/2configure/templates/devicetypes/5194c885eb9fbf38aa000026" class="delete">
           <img src="/icons/cross.png" alt="delete">
       </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**I'm absolutely sure that `$record` contains this element and nothing else.**

No CSS is applied. After `.fadeOut(250)`, the result is:

```
<tr id="5194c885eb9fbf38aa000026" class="record" style="opacity: 1">
    ...
</tr>
```

What gives?!?

jQuery version `1.7.1`

**Edit: full function**

```
function onEntityUpdateSuccess(record_html, statusText, jqXhr, jqForm) {
    var $record = $(".record#" + jqForm.find('input[name="id"]').val());
    var $listingContainer = $record.parents(".listingContainer");
    if(!$listingContainer.is(":visible")) {
         $listingContainer.slideDown(250);
    }

    $record.animate({opacity:0}, 250);
    $record.replaceWith(record_html);
    $record.animate({opacity:0}, 250);
    //$record.fadeIn(1000);
}
```

**UPDATE**

[Aioros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1882497/aioros) has found the issue:

```
$record.replaceWith(record_html);
```

is the culprit. But then why does the second animation not work either? How can I replace the HTML and keep it faded?

Comment: Can you show the code that executes .fadeOut(250)? most likely there's a logic issue causing a fadeIn to be triggered.

Comment: $record = $('.record')   you are using class selector, right?

Comment: @KevinB I don't have `fadeIn` **anywhere** in my code yet. I though that must be the problem but I commented it out.

Comment: @roasted `$record` contains exactly what I want. Why?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester just to be sure! i didn't saw that at first: "I'm absolutely sure that $record contains this element and nothing else."

Comment: @roasted I know but I just edited that in because of your comment ;)

Comment: Works for me -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYX9X/) ?

Comment: According to this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/5B4uT/, your code should work just fine. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Well, `.fadeIn()` may be out of the question, but what about `.show()`?

Comment: maybe a browser issue?

Comment: You remembered document ready, including jQuery etc ?

Comment: @Aioros nope, nowhere.

Comment: Did you open the console and check for errors ?

Comment: Please create a fiddle demonstrating this issue.

Comment: @Corion sorry but I can't, the code is too complex. It's a callback after a form submit. I included the full function.

Comment: What if you only keep the first .animate() and comment out replaceWith() and the second one? Does that opacity work?

Comment: @Aioros YOU GOT IT! but now I wonder why?

Comment: I guess it's because .replaceWith removes the $record element from the DOM, and then your following .animate() has no visible effect.

Comment: @Aioros I'll try with re-assigning it with the return value.

Comment: I've added that as an answer, just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was saying in the comments, `.replaceWith()` removes the `$record` element from the DOM, so the second `.animate()` has no visible effect. You will have to reassign the variable, or use a selector again.

```
function onEntityUpdateSuccess(record_html, statusText, jqXhr, jqForm) {
    var $record = $(".record#" + jqForm.find('input[name="id"]').val());
    var $listingContainer = $record.parents(".listingContainer");
    if(!$listingContainer.is(":visible")) {
         $listingContainer.slideDown(250);
    }

    $record.animate({opacity:0}, 250);
    $record.replaceWith(record_html);

    $record = $(".record#" + jqForm.find('input[name="id"]').val());
    /* or whatever the selector needs to be */

    $record.animate({opacity:0}, 250);
    //$record.fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but I find this is strange behaviour. Why does jQuery not do this by default in the return value? Thanks a bunch by the way.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester - jQuery can handle nodes outside of the DOM in object variables. Sometimes you want to replace an element with another and then move the original elsewhere. If it automatically reassigned on `replaceWith()` return you'd lose that original node. It's more flexible this way, but perhaps a little less intuitive.

Comment: It's not that strange after all. You're basically doing something like `old.replaceWith(new)`, so that you wouldn't expect the variable old to still reference a DOM element in the page.

Comment: Okay, when you look at it that way it does indeed make sense. Thanks to anyone who helped.

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting the opacity to be set to 0? I would thank fadeOut would set the opacity to 0, but alas, there are a couple different options here.

```
$record.animate({opacity:0});
$record.fadeTo('slow', 0);
```

Comment: fadeOut() does set the opacity to 0, if it works, which it obviously does'nt in this case, which again means that most likely neither will the above answer, as it does exactly the same thing ?

Comment: Have you restarted your browser to rule-out cached javascript? (or ctrl+F5)

Comment: This is a strange one, technically the style (I think) would be set to display: none; after the opacity reaches 0.  Maybe something is preventing this?